# Displaying contents of sub-document through Meteor/Mongo

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor

I’m quite new to Meteor and have been playing around with manipulating documents. I have been able to display top-level documents in my collection to the end-user, but was wondering if it's at all possible to display sub-documents and their fields to the user.

My document in Mongo looks like this:

```
"_id" : "qeuhr3X7ErcvpnfXE",
"name" : "Profile",
"Channels" : {
  "channel test" : {
    "name" : "channel test",
    "HighLimit" : 6.5,
    "LowLimit" : 4.5,
    "StopCount" : 10
  }
},
"steps" : {
},
"createdBy" : "psG7RnnD35J6uwceY"
```

My end goal is to have users create `Channels`, and as they create them they appear in a list on the web page and be editable. The piece of the puzzle I'm missing is actually displaying these channels and allowing them to be selected.

I currently have a form already in place that allows users to add as many `channels` as they would like. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A good help could be reading on [mongo data models](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/) your given snippet makes me think that normalization would be a good fit here (see the link)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have looked over the link you provided and for my purposes a denormalized data model would be preferable. Would I still be able to accomplish what I'm trying to do using what I already have?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the sub level documents in this case by

```
Channels['channel test']
```

And the keys by

```
Channels['channel test'].name
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that above you have said you would prefer a denormalised method of storage, my recommendation would be to store each `channel` object in an array called `Channels`.

Then, you need to assign each of them an `_id` so that you can reference them in the future.

You can use the Meteor `random` package to create new IDs for sub-documents:

```
import { random } from meteor/random;
const channelId = random.id()
```

You can then update each channel using their `_id` by using queries like this:

```
Channels.update(
  { _id: "qeuhr3X7ErcvpnfXE", "Channels._id", "bqudr562ercppmh7A" },
  { $set: { "Channels.$.name": "New Channel Name" }}
)
```

This query takes advantage of the Mongo `$` operator which allows you to target an object inside an array, and then update that particular object.